# An object with two very similar arrays, one displays the other does not

Tags: javascript

I have an object with two embedded arrays of objects that seem to me to be almost identical, as seen here in my database:

[image]

But when I try to access one of the arrays in frontend javascript, it's apparently empty. The other is not, as seen here when I log it to the browser console:

[image]

The objects in the arrays are almost exactly the same. I am concerned that the problem is when I push a new object on to the 'stakeholders' array that the asynchronous function is not completing before the page loads again, but I am using async/await in that function before returning the response

```
addStakeholder = async (req, res, next) => {
...
project.stakeholders.push(stakeholder)
await project.save()

res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    project: project
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am likely doing wrong here?

EDIT: Sorry I'll try and add some more detail, so on the form submission there is this.....

```
createStakeholderForm.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
    // getting properties etc, this all works 

    await createStakeholder({ stakeholders, project })
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        location.reload()
    }, 1000)
})
```

which passes it to this axios function....

```
createStakeholder = async (data) => {
try {
    const url = `http://127.0.0.1:3000/stakeholder`

    const res = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data
    })
    if (res.data.status === 'success') {
        showAlert('success', `Stakeholder created`)
    }
} catch (err) {
    showAlert('error', err.response.data.message)
}
```

}

and that routes posts to this function.....

```
addStakeholder = async (req, res, next) => {
const query = { _id: req.body.project }

const project = await Project.findById(query)
const stakeholder = req.body.stakeholders

project.stakeholders.push(stakeholder)
await project.save()

res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
        data: project
    }
})
```

})

Comment: I think this is not the issue.... Please add the whole code so that we can figure the issue out..

Comment: @AbhisarTripathi Sorry I'm not sure what other code I could add that would be helpful - the function adds to the array correctly, my js then awaits that function, and reloads the page after a 1 second delay.

Comment: If the issue is delay in push we can alternatively use `project.stakeholders = project.stakeholders.concat([stakeholder])` which is much faster as compared to `.push` .

Comment: It cannot be the speed of .push. .push is synconous and extremely fast.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not obvious what is wrong from your code. The debugging path is, fortunately.

Start tracing the wire. It sound like things are saving in the database correctly, but are not reaching the frontend. I would console.log in your code on the backend at the call site that queries the database. Confirm its what you expect. Assuming that worked, add another console.log downstream, keep doing that until stakeholder data vanishes. This exercise will show you where in the code stakeholders are getting dropped.